# jQuery\JavaScript - having troubles updating text of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is pretty basic stuff, but I cant figure this out. I'm using jQuery's `DatePicker`. My goal is to display some text with the selected date. If the user chooses a date passed today's date, I'm changing the text to `too late`. When the user re-chooses a future date, I want to set the `div`s text to something and add the selected date inside a `span` which sits inside this `div`. All works except the future date is not appearing. Why?
What is the best practice when it comes to changing content of some element? Can I use `jQuery`s `remove` and then `append`?

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<p id="we_will_start">starting at: <span id="start_date"></span></p>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
    var dateAsString = dateText;
    var selectedDateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    console.log("date object=" + new Date+ " jquery date=" + selectedDateAsObject);
    console.log(dateAsString);
    if(selectedDateAsObject < new Date){
        console.log("bad date. cant start yesterday fool");
         $("#we_will_start").text("too late!");
    }else{
        $("#we_will_start").text("will start at ");
         document.getElementById("start_date").innerHTML = dateAsString;
        }
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh02ecc9/)

Comment: your jquery html(). have a separate span for that and update it. Eg: <p id="we_will_start"><span id="notifyText">starting at: </span><span id="start_date"></span></p>
$("#notifyText").html("will start at ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, just concatenate the date string in your text.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
    var dateAsString = dateText;
    var selectedDateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    console.log("date object=" + new Date+ " jquery date=" + selectedDateAsObject);
    console.log(dateAsString);
    if(selectedDateAsObject < new Date){
        console.log("bad date. cant start yesterday fool");
         $("#we_will_start").text("too late!");
    }else{
        $("#we_will_start").text("will start at " + dateAsString);
        }
    }
});
```

For the span, after you change the text to "too late" you overwritten all the elements inside the paragraph.

Comment: I cant believe it was so simple.. Thanks a lot for the input. Thats what I was missing, didnt realize I was overwriting the elements as well. When its best to use `remove` and `append`?